# Swift - Deleting a value in an array from an element

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of type "User" and I'd like to delete all users that are 10 years old. My code :

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var age: String
}

var array: User = [
    User[name: "AZE", age: "10"]
    User[name: "QSD", age: "37"]
]
```

What is the function for deleting an object from an element of that object? I hope you understood my problem and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to keep only the elements of the array whose `age` property doesn't equal 10.

```
let filtered = array.filter { $0.age != "10" }
```

Unrelated to your question, but why is `age` a `String`? It should be an `Int` instead, since it represents a numeric value. Also, you should always make properties immutable (`let`) by default and only make them mutable (`var`) if they really need to be mutable.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you for your advice and thank you very much for your answer!!